# Implementation of the Singleton pattern on the sql-connection class in c#

Tags: java, c#, mysql, sql-server

I learned the singleton pattern recently ,How to implement the Singleton pattern on sql-connection class ? and how to pass the connection details (database name and table name) to each instance of that Singleton ?

Comment: This is the wrong thing to implement the singleton pattern on.

Comment: "*to each instance of that Singleton*" a singleton only has one instance, its why its called a singleton. Anyway, as mentioned, you never try to cache a DB connection, you will create a whole bunch of other problems

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to implement it by this way:

```
public  class SqlConnection
{
    private static Dictionary<string, SqlConnection> _InsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, SqlConnection>();
    private string _databaseName;
    private string _tableName;
    private SqlConnection(string databaseName,string tableName)
    {
        _databaseName = databaseName;
        _tableName = tableName;
    }
    public static SqlConnection Ins(string databaseName,string tableName)
    {
        if (_InsDictionary.TryGetValue($"{databaseName}_{tableName}",out var ins))   
        {
            ins = new SqlConnection(databaseName,tableName);
            _InsDictionary.Add($"{databaseName}_{tableName}",ins);
        }
            
        return ins;
    }
}

   void Main()
    {

        SqlConnection sqlConnectionA = SqlConnection.Ins("db1","tb1");
        SqlConnection sqlConnectionB = SqlConnection.Ins("db1","tb2");
            
    }
```

Comment: This is not a Singleton.